# finding generators of the zero of vectorfield

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algorithms, galois-theory, finite-fields

I am working on this problem and trying to find an algorithm to solve it:
let $$v= f \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+g \frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$ where $f,g\in \mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$ and want to find the generators of the subring $S$ such that
$v(s)=0 $ $\forall s\in S$. I have succeeded to find the solution for a certain  fixed degree however I don't know how to find the general solution. If I take the stupid example where $f=1$ and $g=0$ it is trivial that the subring $S= F_2[x^2,y]$ but how can I find this result using an algorithm and what is the condition for it to finish.
I greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Comment: I haven't checked how much you can milk out of the following, but this is what I would try. Consider the subring $R=\Bbb{F}_2[x^2,y^2]$ which is trivially a subring of $S$. We have the decomposition of free $R$-modules
$$\Bbb{F}_2[x,y]=R\oplus x R\oplus y R\oplus xy R.\quad(*)$$
We also have the $v$ is a derivation $v(h_1h_2)=h_1v(h_2)+h_2v(h_1)$ making it easier to use the decomposition. I would further write $f$ and $g$ in the form prescribed by $(*)$ and try and see how the land lies.